# Partial derivatives of a multivariable composite function (chain rule)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule, function-and-relation-composition

Say I have this function:
$$z=f(ax, ay)$$
I know how to take this partial derivative by defining $u=ax$ and $v=ay$:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(ax, ay)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(u, v)}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+
                                \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
Which in this case is:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} a+
                                \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}0$$
Let's say $f(u, v)=u^2v$. In that case:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=(2uv)a+
                                (u^2)0=2uva$$
Returning to the original variables:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2a^3xy$$

So here I thought of $f(ax, ay)$ as a composition made like this $f(u(x, y), v(x, y))$.

#### However, is it possible to think it like this?

#### $f(g(x, y))$ where $g(x, y) = (ax, ay)$?

The reason why this seems weird to me is that $f$ seems to only have one "slot". However, I suppose that because $g(x, y)$ outputs two numbers, that this a valid composition. In that case:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
Where $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = (a, 0)$, but what is $\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}$? This could be rewrriten as $\frac{\partial ((ax)^2(ay))}{\partial (ax, ay)}$, but what does differentiating with respect to a vector mean? Is it a gradient in which $$\left(\frac{\partial ((ax)^2(ay))}{\partial (ax)}, \frac{\partial ((ax)^2(ay))}{\partial (ay)}\right) ?$$
Which makes the final result be $$\left(\frac{\partial ((ax)^2(ay))}{\partial (ax)}, \frac{\partial ((ax)^2(ay))}{\partial (ay)}\right)(a, 0) = a2(ax)(ay)=2a^3xy ?$$
I get to the right result by assuming this, but I have no idea why it works (or if it is even right).
Not a maths student so simple explanations are appreciated. Tyvm.

Comment: When you write $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, you are essentially doing a dot product $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v})\cdot (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x})$. Also since dot products and multiplication with scalar is commutative,  this explains why the results are the same.

Comment: Although the results are always the same, I guess this does not really answer the question "is the latter case legitimate/ what is the intuition"? Maybe it is just a counter-intuitive way of re-writing the definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah I get what you say, although I find the second composition more intuitive myself haha. I'm still not certain if the 2nd composition is right though, what do you think?